# github configure machine to use existing ssh key

Tags: git, github, ssh

Background:

I had a personal account that was working fine with github, then my employer gave me a new github account and so i configured my github account to use my machine generated SSH key. Now my old machine is replaced ....

How do i configure this new machine to check-in check-out code to github..

do i generate and add another key to the account?
it is also asking me for email account..when i give my old(xxx@y.com) (email added on git hub) it says:

```
error: invalid key: xxx@y.com
```

Directly adding it says

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

 git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
 git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'x y@DESKTOP-8ITRR8F.(no                                                                                                                                                                                               ne)')
```

**UPDATE**

windows 10 doesnot allow creating a folder .ssh in c:/users/samra/..
and when i try to generate key (thinking it may create a .ssh in the process) it says

```
Saving key failed: No such file or directory found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps to generate another ssh key:

1. from cmd prompt go to c:/users/xyz/mkdir .ssh
2. open gitbash from c:/program files/git/bin/bash.exe
3. type

   ```
    ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your-email-address"
   ```
4. Enter full path when asked for the file name (this is important)

   ```
    C:/Users/xyz/.ssh/id_rsa_ge
   ```
5. Enter pass phrase..and your key shall be generated.
6. Login to your Github account "SSH and GPG keys" click **New SSH Key** button
7. Open your id_rsa_ge.pub file in a text file eg notepad and copy everything and paste into the key dialog..give any title of your choice.
8. In git bash Type

   ```
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_ge
   ```
9. If it says "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.", do the following commands

   ```
    ssh-agent
    eval $(ssh-agent)
   ```

it should return a agent pid
Now again repeat step 8.

Create config file in .ssh folder and type

```
#Default GitHub
Host github.com
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host github-ge
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_ge
```

Now use git

```
git add .
git commit ...
git push origin master
```

Note: before reinstalling your OS always take a backup of keys

Comment: But the question is to configure the machine to an existing ssh key. 
Hopefully, I am not wrong in understanding the question.

Comment: thanks for your response. Could you write a literal name of the config file inner .ssh folder please.

And when you say inner content of the config file, "User git", Do I need only to change the work "git" with my username o the full text "User git" for my username?

Answer (score 1):

1.) The e-mail address configuration is for your local copy, it got nothing to do with github, git needs to know your info so it can fill it in when you do a commit.

2.) the key -- of course you can generate a new key and add it to github, or you can copy the private/public keypair to your new machine, on Linux Machines you usually find it in ~/.ssh .

3.) the error you get is, because you don't have a valid key on your new machine yet. This is kind of like you try to login using a password, and instead of entering the password you just hit enter... no key, no access ;-) so you got the 2 options in 2.) to fix this.

Comment: So u r saying that i have to generate a new key and then add it to github..and i have no other choice..

Comment: ok how do i copy the private/public key pair to my new machine..STEPs?

Comment: Well, I usually scp it from old machine to new machine.